# LINQ with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq, list, observablecollection

I have a ObservableCollection property that I need to manipulate with LINQ.

What I want to do is take the first collection and remove items from another collection, based on the item's property.

This is what I have so far:

```
ItemsObservableCollection = ItemsObservableCollection.Where(i=>!selectedItemsObservableCollection.Any(y=> y.name == i.Name);
```

If I do it this way, I get a casting error that says I cannot cast an IEnumerable to a ObservableCollection. If I save the value into a var, it does exactly what I want:

```
    var collectionItems= ItemsObservableCollection.Where(i=>!selectedItemsObservableCollection.Any(y=> y.name == i.Name);
```

but I need it to update the ObservableCollection property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new collection, you could just remove the items you want from the original. This is preferable if, for example, you're working in WPF and have bound the observable collection to a control.

```
var itemsToRemove = ItemsObservableCollection.Where(
    i => !selectedItemsObservableCollection.Any(y => y.name == i.Name)).ToList();

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
    ItemsObservableCollection.Remove(item);
```

*(Have to use* `ToList()` *to avoid a "collection was modified" error.)*

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and yes I am working with WPF and my collection is bound to a control! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Well, you've got an ObservableCollection ctor which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`

so you may do

```
ItemsObservablecollection = new ObservableCollection<DesiredType>(ItemsObservableCollection.Where(i=>!selectedItemsObservableCollection.Any(y=> y.name == i.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. That is .NET API for computations over [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) and [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) (ObservableCollection) objects. Results of the computations are INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyColectionChanged (ObservableCollection) objects.

Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
var collectionItems= ItemsObservableCollection.Filtering(i=> 
    !selectedItemsObservableCollection.AnyComputing(y => y.name == i.Name).Value);
```

collectionItems is [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) and reflects all the changes in the ItemsObservableCollection collection and Name properties. Ensure that all properties mentioned in the code above notify of changes through the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.